# How to use Axios inside an express router

Tags: node.js, axios, nodejs-server

I have a `React` front-end that make an `axios` request to the back-end.

While in the back-end, under some circumstances, I need to make another axios request.

But the `axios.patch` doesn't run: it seems to executes the line, but after that it not execute the `.then` nor the `.error` lines.

I have a breakpoint set into the `router.patch('/stripeUser', (req, res, next) => {}` function, but it is not triggered.

If I try to call the same call use `Postman`, it succeeds.

Here is the back-end code:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {

    const params = {
        user: req.body.data[0].user,
    }

    const customer = params.user.stripeId !== undefined
        ? await stripe.customers.retrieve(params.user.stripeId)
        : await stripe.customers.create({
            email: params.user.email
        });

    if (params.user.stripeId === undefined && customer.id !== undefined) {
        axios.patch('https://xxx.domain.com/users/update', { data: [{ userId: params.user.userId, stripeId: customer.id }] })
            .then((usr) => {
                console.log("User updated: stripeId: " + usr.user.stripeId)
                newCustomer = usr.user;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    const intermediate = usr.user.someTransform();

    res(intermediate) ???
    return intermediate ???
```

A secondary question:

If the `axios.fetch` should run, how could I pass its results `usr` to the rest of the program?

Comment: About your secondary question, why not using a "user" global var ?

Comment: This is maybe just a copy paste mistake but there is a missing quote after your axios url param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `await` instead of `then`, since the function may return before axios has resolved the request response you may not be able to use the data you get in the promise callback in the same function if you don't wait the resolution.

```js
const usr = await axios.patch('https://xxx.domain.com/users/update', 
    { data: [{ userId: params.user.userId, stripeId: customer.id }] })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
const newCustomer = usr.user;
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing quote missing in the axios patch call.

```
axios.patch('https://xxx.domain.com/users/update', { data: [{ userId: params.user.userId, stripeId: customer.id }] })
                .then((usr) => {
                    console.log("User updated: stripeId: " + usr.user.stripeId)
                    newCustomer = usr.user;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```